# How to access back-forward list of UIWebView

Tags: list, uiwebview, count, back, forward

How can we get the no of list items in bad-forward list of UIWebView? What I wanted to do is when back list is empty (ie. when there is no link to go back) navigate to previous controller. So wanted to know the count in the list.

Thanks in advance

Sayali

Answer (score 2):

you dont want to access backforward list just for that, simply use .canGoBack property.
Here is the way to do it anyways (be carefull, private API here) :

```
    id webview111      = [self _documentView];    /// self - uiwebview subclass
    coreWebV           = [webview111 webView];
    backForwardList    = [coreWebV backForwardList];
```